# When running a simple peace of code, I reach an EOF Error. Can someone explain to me EOF?

Tags: python-3.x

```
is42 = False
while True:
    d = int(input())
if d == 42:
    is42 = True
if not is42:
    print(d)
```

My input is as follows

> 1
>
> 4
>
> 23
>
> 42
>
> 58

My output is as follows

> 1
>
> 4
>
> 23

then the error happens

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./prog.py", line 5, in 
>   EOFError: EOF when reading a line

I'm doing a spoj problem and it says to reprint all input till 42 appears. How does the computer see and deal with or better yet what is an EOF (End of File) Error?

Comment: when do you break out  of the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your error, does not seem to happen for me. But the code that you have given is wrong. The while loop will continue for ever.

This should do what you want.

```
while True:
    d = int(input())
    if d == 42:
        break
    print(d)
```